# Is it possible to use Jquery to detect next id or anchor and use it to create a new div around another element?

Tags: jquery

The HTML I have is something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="oneClass">
            <img src="http:image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="anotherClass" id="oneID">
            <div class="twoClass" id="randomID">
                <cite class="user">
                    <a href="http://someURL" >Name</a>
                </cite>
                <span class="icon user"></span>
                <span class="threeClass">
                    <a href="http:URL#oneID">some text</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="content" id="randomID">some words content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="oneClass">
            <img src="http:image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="anotherClass" id="anotherID">
            <div class="twoClass" id="randomID">
                <cite class="user">
                    <a href="http://someURL" >Name</a>
                </cite>
                <span class="icon user"></span>
                <span class="threeClass">
                    <a href="http:URL#anotherID">some text</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="content" id="randomID">some words content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I need is to find a way to detect the next ID after oneClass and use to create another div around oneClass.
Example:

```
    <div id="container">
       <ul>
        <li> 
      <div id="myName_oneID">
            <div class="oneClass">
         <img src="http:image.jpg">
            </div>
      </div>
         <div class="anotherClass" id="oneID">
            <div class="twoClass" id="randomID">
                <cite class="user">
               <a href="http://someURL" >Name</a>
                 </cite>
                    <span class="threeClass">
                         <a href="http:URL#oneID">some text</a>
                    </span>
              </div>
                <p class="content" id="randomID">
                   some words content
                </p>
        </div>
     </li>
      <li>
        <div id="myName_anotherID">
             <div class="oneClass">
                <img src="http:image.jpg">
             </div>
         </div>
             <div class="anotherClass" id="anotherID">
                 <div class="twoClass" id="randomID">
                     <cite class="user">
                    <a href="http://someURL" >Name</a>
                      </cite>
                     <span class="threeClass">
                    <a href="http:URL#anotherID">some text</a>
                     </span>
                 </div>
             <p class="content" id="randomID">
                   some words content
             </p>
          </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to get it from the anchor like this:

```
    $(".threeClass a").map(function () {
    var myID ="myName_" + this.hash.replace(/#/, '');
    //alert(myID);
$(".oneClass").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap("<div id='" + myID + "' />");
});

});
```

If I test the alert(myID), it detects correctly but when I try use it to wrap a new div, it creates it with the same Id for all oneClass.

Can it be done?

I'm a newbie at javascript or Jquery and appreciatte the help or guidance on the right way.

Thank you.

Comment: Ugh! Scrolling sideways sucks...

Comment: @elclanrs so edit the HTML. You have the rep for it.

Comment: No, I can't edit the html. It's javascript generated. That's why I need a script to do it.

Comment: You need to format your code properly, otherwise it's unreadable. I did the first one for you, maybe you could do the other?

Comment: Thank you ahren. I didn't realized that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.oneClass').each(function(){
    id=$(this).next().attr('id');
    $(this).wrap('<div></div>').parent().attr('id', 'myName_'+id);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/5z3k4/3/) (See the source).

Comment: That works perfect. the only problem I see now is that depending on how many li there are on the page, so it takes the script to load, but if there isn't a way around it, I can use it like it is. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question.

Comment: Not a question, sorry. Your script works perfectly. It's just some pages can have a lot of li and I was wondering if that could affect page loading time but I tested onsite and works great. :)

Comment: Oh ! it won't make any problem.